# Ubuntu Linux, Get User Login, LogOff, Lock, UnLock Time

Tags: ubuntu

We need to monitor the user based on User Login, LogOff, Lock and UnLock Time. How to get these details from Ubuntu Linux.

I got this link [Login Details](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/) for the User Login, LogOff, Lock and UnLock Time, but I don't know how to call or execute in Ubuntu.

Or if there is any user monitoring(Application Used, Idle Time) shell program, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Babu, questions receive better answers when you ask a specific question, such as 'I want to find out when a user logged in on Ubuntu?'

Answer (score 0):

Capture login:
Place a script file in the path

```
"/etc/init.d/Login.sh"
```

Make the file executable

```
chmod +x Login.sh
```

Capture logoff:
Place a script file in the path

```
"/etc/profile.d/LogOff.sh"
```

Make the file executable

```
chmod +x LogOff.sh
```

Capturing Lock and UnLock

Place the below bash script in a file and call it in the file "/etc/init.d/Login.sh". So that after login the below bash script gets called and listen for the events.

```
gdbus monitor -y -d org.freedesktop.login1 | 
  while read x; do 
    case "$x" in 
        LockHint) 
          if [[ "$x" == "$lock" ]] ; then 
             echo "lock" 
          fi 
          if [[ "$x" == "$unLock" ]] ; then 
             echo "UnLock" 
          fi 
     ;; 
   esac
```